# Confusion while deriving from std::tuple, can not handle std::get

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, libstdc++, stdtuple

My basic idea was to derive my own class from std::tuple to get some helper types inside like this:

```
template <typename ... T>
class TypeContainer: public std::tuple<T...>
{   
    public:
        using BaseType = std::tuple<T...>;
        static const size_t Size = sizeof...(T);
        TypeContainer(T... args):std::tuple<T...>(args...){};

        using index_sequence = std::index_sequence_for<T...>;
};
```

Now I try to use the code as follows:

```
using MyType_tuple_with_empty =         std::tuple<       std::tuple<float,int>,    std::tuple<>,    std::tuple<int>>;
using MyType_typecontainer_with_empty = TypeContainer< TypeContainer<float,int>, TypeContainer<>, TypeContainer<int>>;

using MyType_tuple_non_empty =          std::tuple<       std::tuple<float,int>,    std::tuple<int>,    std::tuple<int>>;
using MyType_typecontainer_non_empty =  TypeContainer< TypeContainer<float,int>, TypeContainer<int>, TypeContainer<int>>;

template <typename T>
void Do( const T& parms )
{
    // The following lines result in errors if TypeContainer with
    // empty element comes in. The empty element is in std::get<1> which
    // is NOT accessed here!
    std::cout << std::get<0>(std::get<0>(parms)) << " ";
    std::cout << std::get<1>(std::get<0>(parms)) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::get<0>(std::get<2>(parms)) << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    MyType_tuple_with_empty         p1{{ 1.2,3},{},{1}};
    Do( p1 );

    MyType_typecontainer_with_empty p2{{ 1.2,3},{},{1}};
    Do( p2 ); // << this line raise the error

    MyType_tuple_non_empty          p3{{ 1.2,3},{4},{1}};
    Do( p3 );

    MyType_typecontainer_non_empty  p4{{ 1.2,3},{4},{1}};
    Do( p4 );
}
```

If I compile with `Do(p2)` I get the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to '`get(const TypeContainer<TypeContainer<float, int>, TypeContainer<>, TypeContainer<int> >&)`'

Can someone explain why the existence of an empty `TypeContainer` in connection with `std::get` will result in that problem?

Edit:
Additional information:

The lines

```
MyType_tuple_with_empty         p1{{{ 1.2,3},{},{1}}};
MyType_tuple_non_empty          p3{{ 1.2,3},{4},{1}};
```

can not compiled with gcc5.2.0 but with gcc6.1.0. This is a bit mysterious because I remember that the constructor of the tuple is indeed explicit. Why this works with gcc6.1.0? But that is not the problem I search for :-)

Another hint:
The code which I have problems with seems to compile with clang3.5.0.

A bit hard to understand...

Edit2:
Digging through the error lists ( a long one :-) ) I found:

> /opt/linux-gnu_5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/tuple|832 col 5| note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   main.cpp|104 col 45| note:   '`std::tuple<_Elements ...>`' is an ambiguous base class of '`TypeContainer<TypeContainer<float, int>, TypeContainer<>, TypeContainer<int> >`'
>   ||          `std::cout << std::get<0>(std::get<0>(parms)) << " "`;

Seems that in libg++ someone derives multiple times from any tuple type which seems to be a broken library. Searching for this topic brings me to: [Empty nested tuples error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999062/empty-nested-tuples-error)

Is this really related? Same bug or a new one :-)

Comment: perhaps a [simplified case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8de00d9fcaa3df1c)

Comment: This is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55713) that was fixed in GCC 11. (The core issue being `std::is_base_of_v<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<std::tuple<>>>` through private inheritance in the buggy implementation). Related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13902910, showing your code should work and GCC was buggy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to add your container versions of get functions:

```
template <std::size_t I, typename ...T>
decltype(auto) get(TypeContainer<T...>&& v)
{
    return std::get<I>(static_cast<std::tuple<T...>&&>(v));
}
template <std::size_t I, typename ...T>
decltype(auto) get(TypeContainer<T...>& v)
{
    return std::get<I>(static_cast<std::tuple<T...>&>(v));
}
template <std::size_t I, typename ...T>
decltype(auto) get(TypeContainer<T...> const& v)
{
    return std::get<I>(static_cast<std::tuple<T...> const&>(v));
}
```

And just use `get` not `std::get` in `Do` kind of functions. Compiler is able to select namespace from arguments.

I guess, I am not sure, that this is because gcc has [EBO - Empty  Base Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076961/common-base-class-breaks-empty-base-class-optimization-for-tuples) - implemented in its tuples. What are exact reason it is quite hard to guess. You might consider to report this in [gcc bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=tuple).

---

BTW, it is not good habit to derive from STD classes. If you started from compisition, not inheritance, then you would need to provide your own `get` functions and you would not observe this error, saving probably a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are 2 things I think about: First: accessing a tuple with an empty tuple should not behave different to access a tuple with non empty tuples. Second: clang works. I will try your code as workarround for the problem, but I believe there is a bug in libg++... another one. I have already list of bugs reported... with no response :-(

Comment: I am almost 99% sure this is because EBO - I looked into implementation - there are some template magic things being done to have EBO -  that is not easy to read, neither I have time to do it. Please report this. And consider to use composition. CLang probably does not have EBO, or implemented it in better way.

Comment: And why EBO - because gcc implements tuple by inheritance: each tuple element add new level of inheritance  - when some element is empty - this very base class would occupy some memory - so it is something that could be optimized