# Initialze a tuple of tuples

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14

I can initialize a `std::tuple` like this

```
std::tuple<int,float> t1{ 1,2.2 }; // works
```

If I want to initialize a tuple of tuples:

```
std::tuple<std::tuple<int,float> > t2{ 1,2.2}; // fails on gcc5.2.0 & gcc6.1.0
std::tuple<std::tuple<int,float> > t2{{ 1,2.2}}; // works on gcc6.1.0, fails for gcc5.2.0
```

So I am a bit confused if one of the above lines is correct c++14 code or not.

Simple question: Is it possible to direct initialize a tuple of tuples without using `std::make_tuple` or other helper types?

I am a bit in fear because of other problems found today like: [Confusion while deriving from std::tuple, can not handle std::get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186443/confusion-while-deriving-from-stdtuple-can-not-handle-stdget/37188019#37188019)

Comment: TL;DR: wait for C++17. :)

Comment: @erip Maybe this is the reason while gcc 6.1.0 compiles in c++14 mode without an error :-)

Comment: I think that's probably a bug... C++14 shouldn't have any C++17 features - standard features aren't backwards compatible, nor are bug fixes.

Comment: That is a definitely a bug. But it looks that a new feature for c++17 has opened that door. That's why I write a ":-)".  I will prepare a bug report for that later...

Comment: tuple<tuple<int, float>> t1 = tuple<tuple<int, float>>{tuple<int, float>{1,2.2}};

Comment: works on gcc4.9.2